Sending All Overworld Players To Nether
Is there a way to teleport all players in the overworld to one spot in the nether using a repeating command block on Bedrock Edition?

Please try these steps:

Place a repeating command block in the overworld where you want the
teleportation to occur.

Set the command block to repeat and always active.

Enter the following command into the command block:
/execute as @a in minecraft:the_nether run tp @s ~ 128 ~



This command will teleport all players to a position 128 blocks above their current location in the Nether.
Make sure to adjust the coordinates (the ~ 128 ~ part) to the desired location in the Nether. You can modify the Y-coordinate to place players at different heights within the Nether. For example, if you want them to appear at the Nether roof, you can use ~ 128 ~.

/execute in nether run tp @a 0 0 0

[Teleports all players to 0 0 0 in the Nether]
Sadly, in MCBE we cannot use if/unless dimension so you cannot check if they are in the nether or end already.

0 0 0 is in the void and will likely kill your friends
